# IndexOutOfBoundsException For Android Spinner OnItemSelected

Tags: android, listview, fragment, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I have the following android spinner setup within a fragment:

```
ArrayList<String> subjects=new ArrayList<String>();
                subjects.add("Option0");
                subjects.add("Option1");
                subjects.add("Option2");
                subjects.add("Option2");

                Spinner ExamSpinner = (Spinner)rlayout2.findViewById(R.id.SpinnerExam);
                ListView listview=(ListView)rlayout2.findViewById(R.id.list1);

                ArrayAdapter <String> subjectAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subjects);

                subjectAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                listview.setAdapter(subjectAdapter);    

                listview.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { 

                        switch(adapterView.getId()){

                        case 0:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "ALEX",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                        case 1:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "ALEX",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                        case 2:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "ALEX",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                        case 3:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "ALEX",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                        }
                    } 

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                        return;
                    } 
                });
```

And it is giving an IndexOutOfBoundsException. The logcat is below:

```
12-30 00:52:19.020: E/AndroidRuntime(16589): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 00:52:19.020: E/AndroidRuntime(16589): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
12-30 00:52:19.020: E/AndroidRuntime(16589):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
12-30 00:52:19.020: E/AndroidRuntime(16589):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
12-30 00:52:19.020: E/AndroidRuntime(16589):    at com.gloxci.studentreport.ExamScheduleFragment$10.onItemClick(ExamScheduleFragment.java:359)
12-30 00:52:19.020: E/AndroidRuntime(16589):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
12-30 00:52:19.020: E/AndroidRuntime(16589):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
12-30 00:52:19.020: E/AndroidRuntime(16589):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2855)
12-30 00:52:19.020: E/AndroidRuntime(16589):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3529)
12-30 00:52:19.020: E/AndroidRuntime(16589):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-30 00:52:19.020: E/AndroidRuntime(16589):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-30 00:52:19.020: E/AndroidRuntime(16589):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-30 00:52:19.020: E/AndroidRuntime(16589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-30 00:52:19.020: E/AndroidRuntime(16589):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 00:52:19.020: E/AndroidRuntime(16589):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-30 00:52:19.020: E/AndroidRuntime(16589):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-30 00:52:19.020: E/AndroidRuntime(16589):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-30 00:52:19.020: E/AndroidRuntime(16589):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-30 00:54:24.602: E/Trace(17678): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

I know this is to do with listener, as it works fine without, but causes the app to crash when I click on an item on the spinner.

I am unsure about the line:

```
            listview.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
```

as I would normally use;

```
ExamSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
```

to set the listener for a spinner, but this caused it to crash and I had to use

```
listview.setAdapter(SubjectAdapter)
```

to get it to display the spinner in the first place.

So my question is, why is it giving an OutOfBoundsException, as far as I can see everything is setup correctly.

Here is the whole class:

```
package com.gloxci.studentreport;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.gloxci.studentreport.database.DBAdapter;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ExamScheduleFragment extends CustomFragment{

    int mYear;
    int mMonth;
    int mDay;
    TextView mDateDisplay;
    //CustomViewPager vp;
    DBAdapter dbAdapter;
    String examTitle="";
    ArrayList<StudentData> students=new ArrayList<StudentData>();
    ArrayList<String> exams=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> subexams=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> EIDs=new ArrayList<String>();
    HashMap<String, String> percentages=new HashMap<String, String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterExam;
    String selectedExam="";
    String total_marks="";
    boolean isEdit=false;
    int lastPage=0;
    ListAdapterPercentage adapter;
    public ExamScheduleFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        MainActivity.setTitle("Exam Schedule");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        ViewPagerAdapter pAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity(), new RelativeLayout[]{setLayout1(inflater),setLayout2(inflater),setLayout3(inflater),setLayout4(inflater)});
        vp=new CustomViewPager(getActivity());
        vp.setAdapter(pAdapter);
        vp.setPagingEnabled(false);
        vp.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(lastPage==3 &&arg0==2)
                {
                    vp.setCurrentItem(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    lastPage=arg0;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        dbAdapter=new DBAdapter(getActivity());
        return vp;
    }
    RelativeLayout setLayout3(LayoutInflater inflater)
    {
        RelativeLayout rlayout1=(RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.exams, null);
        final EditText edMarks=(EditText)rlayout1.findViewById(R.id.edMarks);
        ArrayList<String> subjects=new ArrayList<String>();
        dbAdapter=new DBAdapter(getActivity());
        Cursor mCursor = dbAdapter.AllSubject();

        getActivity().startManagingCursor(mCursor);

        mCursor.moveToFirst();

         while (mCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
             String Code = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Code"));
             String Name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Name"));
             subjects.add(Code+"-"+Name);
             mCursor.moveToNext();

         }

        final Spinner spSubject=(Spinner)rlayout1.findViewById(R.id.spSubject);
        ArrayAdapter<String> subjectAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subjects);
        subjectAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spSubject.setAdapter(subjectAdapter);

        final Spinner spSemester=(Spinner)rlayout1.findViewById(R.id.spSemester);
        ArrayList<String> semesters=new ArrayList<String>();
        mCursor = dbAdapter.AllSemester();

        getActivity().startManagingCursor(mCursor);

        mCursor.moveToFirst();

         while (mCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
             String Name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Name"));
             semesters.add(Name);
             mCursor.moveToNext();

         }
         ArrayAdapter<String> semesterAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, semesters);
         semesterAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spSemester.setAdapter(semesterAdapter);
        final TimePicker tp=(TimePicker)rlayout1.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

        Button btnSave=(Button)rlayout1.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(edMarks.getText().toString().compareTo("")==0){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enter the Marks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                String sem="";
                if(spSemester.getSelectedItem()!=null)
                {
                    sem=spSemester.getSelectedItem().toString();
                }
                total_marks=edMarks.getText().toString();
                String value=spSubject.getSelectedItem().toString()+" - "+sem;
                value+="\nMarks: "+edMarks.getText().toString()+"\n"+mDay+"/"+mMonth+"/"+mYear+"\n" +tp.getCurrentHour()+":"+tp.getCurrentMinute();
                if(tp.getCurrentHour()<12)
                {
                    value+=" AM";
                }
                else
                {
                    value+=" PM";
                }

                ShowAlertDialog2(value);
            }
        });

        Button btnDate=(Button)rlayout1.findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate);
        mDateDisplay=(TextView)rlayout1.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
         updateDisplay();
        btnDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                        mDateSetListener,
                        mYear, mMonth, mDay).show();
            }
        });
        return rlayout1;
    }

    RelativeLayout setLayout2(LayoutInflater inflater)
    {
        RelativeLayout rlayout2=(RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendance_stdlist, null);
        ListView listview=(ListView)rlayout2.findViewById(R.id.list1);
        adapterExam=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, subexams);
        listview.setAdapter(adapterExam);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                selectedExam=subexams.get(arg2);
                total_marks=selectedExam.split("\n")[1].split(" ")[1];
                adapter.marks=total_marks;
                Cursor mCursor1 = dbAdapter.StudentMarks(selectedExam);
                percentages.clear();
                if(mCursor1.getCount()>0)
                {
                    getActivity().startManagingCursor(mCursor1);

                    mCursor1.moveToFirst();

                     while (mCursor1.isAfterLast() == false) {

                         String Std_ID = mCursor1.getString(mCursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("SID"));
                         String Std_Prcnt = mCursor1.getString(mCursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Marks"));

                         percentages.put(Std_ID, Std_Prcnt);

                         mCursor1.moveToNext();

                     }

                     ShowAlertDialog();

                }
                else
                {
                    vp.setCurrentItem(3);
                }


                Cursor mCursor = dbAdapter.AllStudents();

                getActivity().startManagingCursor(mCursor);

                mCursor.moveToFirst();
                students.clear();
                 while (mCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                     String Std_Name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Name"));
                     String Std_ID = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("SID"));
                     StudentData sd=new StudentData();
                     sd.name=Std_Name;
                     sd.id=Std_ID;
                     sd.percentage=percentages.get(Std_ID);
                     students.add(sd);
                     mCursor.moveToNext();

                 }
                 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
        listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DeleteDialog dd=new DeleteDialog(getActivity(),"SubExams");
                dd.Show(subexams, EIDs, adapterExam, arg2);
                return true;
            }
        });




        Button btnSave=(Button)rlayout2.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setText("Add");
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stu
                vp.next();

            }
        });
        return rlayout2;
    }
    void ShowAlertDialog2(final String value)
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        alert.setTitle("Are you sure want to save");
        //alert.setMessage(msg);


        alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog1, int whichButton) {
         // Do something with value!

            if(subexams.contains(value))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Already Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            subexams.add(value);
            adapterExam.notifyDataSetChanged();
            DBAdapter dbAdapter=new DBAdapter(getActivity());
            dbAdapter.insertExams(examTitle, value);


            Cursor mCursor1 = dbAdapter.SubExams(examTitle);

            getActivity().startManagingCursor(mCursor1);

            mCursor1.moveToFirst();
            subexams.clear();
            EIDs.clear();
             while (mCursor1.isAfterLast() == false) {
                 String Std_Name = mCursor1.getString(mCursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("SubTitle"));
                 String Std_EID = mCursor1.getString(mCursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("EID"));
                 subexams.add(Std_Name);
                 EIDs.add(Std_EID);
                 mCursor1.moveToNext();

             }
             adapterExam.notifyDataSetChanged();
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            vp.previous();
          }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.

          }
        });

        alert.show();   

    }
    RelativeLayout setLayout1(LayoutInflater inflater)
    {
        final RelativeLayout rlayout2=(RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendance_stdlist, null);
        ListView listview=(ListView)rlayout2.findViewById(R.id.list1);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                MainActivity.setTitle(exams.get(arg2));
                examTitle =exams.get(arg2);

                Cursor mCursor1 = dbAdapter.SubExams(examTitle);

                getActivity().startManagingCursor(mCursor1);

                mCursor1.moveToFirst();
                subexams.clear();
                EIDs.clear();
                 while (mCursor1.isAfterLast() == false) {
                     String Std_Name = mCursor1.getString(mCursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("SubTitle"));
                     String Std_EID = mCursor1.getString(mCursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("EID"));
                     subexams.add(Std_Name);
                     EIDs.add(Std_EID);
                     mCursor1.moveToNext();

                 }
                 adapterExam.notifyDataSetChanged();
                vp.next();
            }
        });

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, exams);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        DBAdapter dbAdapter=new DBAdapter(getActivity());
        Cursor mCursor1 = dbAdapter.Exams();

        getActivity().startManagingCursor(mCursor1);

        mCursor1.moveToFirst();
        exams.clear();
         while (mCursor1.isAfterLast() == false) {
             String Std_Name = mCursor1.getString(mCursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Title"));
             exams.add(Std_Name);
             mCursor1.moveToNext();

         }
        Button btnSave=(Button)rlayout2.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setText("Add");
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ArrayList<String> subjects=new ArrayList<String>();
                subjects.add("Option0");
                subjects.add("Option1");
                subjects.add("Option2");
                subjects.add("Option2");

                Spinner ExamSpinner = (Spinner)rlayout2.findViewById(R.id.SpinnerExam);
                ListView listview=(ListView)rlayout2.findViewById(R.id.list1);

                ArrayAdapter <String> subjectAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subjects);

                subjectAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                listview.setAdapter(subjectAdapter);    

                listview.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { 

                        switch(adapterView.getId()){

                        case 0:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "ALEX",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                        case 1:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "ALEX",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                        case 2:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "ALEX",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                        case 3:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "ALEX",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                        }
                    } 

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                        return;
                    } 
                }); 

                // TODO Auto-generated method stu
                /**AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                alert.setTitle("Exam Title");
                //alert.setMessage("Message");

                // Set an EditText view to get user input 
                final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
                alert.setView(input);

                alert.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                  String value = input.getText().toString();
                  // Do something with value!
                    exams.add(value);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  }
                });

                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                  }
                });

                alert.show();*/
            }
        });
        return rlayout2;
    }
    RelativeLayout setLayout4(LayoutInflater inflater)
    {
        RelativeLayout rlayout2=(RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendance_stdlist, null);
        ListView listview=(ListView)rlayout2.findViewById(R.id.list1);


        adapter=new ListAdapterPercentage(getActivity(), R.layout.listitem_m, R.id.tvAlertTitle, students);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button btnSave=(Button)rlayout2.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stu
                if(isEdit)
                {
                    for(int i=0; i<students.size();i++)
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            if(students.get(i).percentage.compareTo("")==0)
                                continue;
                            dbAdapter.updateMarks(selectedExam, students.get(i).id, 
                            students.get(i).percentage);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int i=0; i<students.size();i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                        if(students.get(i).percentage.compareTo("")==0)
                            continue;
                        dbAdapter.insertMarks(selectedExam, students.get(i).id, 
                            students.get(i).percentage);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }
                    }
                }
                vp.setCurrentItem(1);
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return rlayout2;
    }
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    updateDisplay();
                }
            };

    private void updateDisplay() {
        mDateDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
            .append(mDay).append("-")
            .append(mYear).append(" "));
    }

    void ShowAlertDialog()
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        alert.setTitle("Already Added");
        alert.setMessage("Do you want to");


        alert.setPositiveButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
         // Do something with value!
            isEdit=true;

            vp.setCurrentItem(3);
          }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.

          }
        });

        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: but where you `setAdapter` to your `spinner`?

Comment: post `ExamScheduleFragment.java:359`

Comment: Why adding same item twice?
 subjects.add("Option2");
                subjects.add("Option2");

Comment: you get an error on `MainActivity.setTitle(exams.get(arg2));` , your `exam` size is `0` and you try to get first index of that, this is return `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, to create the listener I had to do the following:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                            long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "0",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        }


                    }
                });
```